# class sabir.test.jms.entity.Message nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am following [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-tutorial) tutorial, i need to create a class where it has a function to convert any object to xml.

in the example, the following code is being used:

```
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;  

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;  
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;  


public class ObjectToXml {  
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{  
    JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);  

    Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();  
    marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);  

    Employee emp1=new Employee(1,"Vimal Jaiswal",50000);  

    marshallerObj.marshal(emp1, new FileOutputStream("employee.xml"));  

}  
}
```

here is my code:

```
package sabir.test.jms.services;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.PropertyException;

import sabir.test.jms.entity.Message;  



public class ObjectToXml {
    public static void convertObjectToXml (Object object) throws IOException, JAXBException
    {


    JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.ExCourse.class);  

    Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();  
    marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);  

    FileOutputStream xmlFile = new FileOutputStream(object.getClass().getName() + ".xml");

    marshallerObj.marshal(object, xmlFile);  

    } 

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Message msg = new Message ("1","MT 103", "Sabir","Banda","CIMB","May Bank", 1000);
        try {
            convertObjectToXml (msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to convert any message to XML, when I implemented I got this error:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class sabir.test.jms.entity.Message nor any of its super class is known to this context.
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:582)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:482)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
>       at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
>       at sabir.test.jms.services.ObjectToXml.convertObjectToXml(ObjectToXml.java:31)
>       at sabir.test.jms.services.ObjectToXml.main(ObjectToXml.java:39)

why am I getting this error?

### EDIT

I edited this line of code to the following:

```
    JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());
```

now I am not getting any error, but my program is terminated.

here is my Message class:

```
package sabir.test.jms.entity;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


import java.io.Serializable;


@XmlRootElement  
public class Message implements Serializable{


    private String id; 
    private String type;

    private String senderName;
    private String recieverName;

    private String senderBankName;
    private String recieverBankName;

    private long amount;

    public Message() {} 
    public Message(String id, String type, String senderName, String recieverName, String senderBankName,
            String recieverBankName, long amount) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.senderName = senderName;
        this.recieverName = recieverName;
        this.senderBankName = senderBankName;
        this.recieverBankName = recieverBankName;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @XmlAttribute  
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getSenderName() {
        return senderName;
    }

    public void setSenderName(String senderName) {
        this.senderName = senderName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getRecieverName() {
        return recieverName;
    }


    public void setRecieverName(String recieverName) {
        this.recieverName = recieverName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getSenderBankName() {
        return senderBankName;
    }

    public void setSenderBankName(String senderBankName) {
        this.senderBankName = senderBankName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getRecieverBankName() {
        return recieverBankName;
    }

    public void setRecieverBankName(String recieverBankName) {
        this.recieverBankName = recieverBankName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(long amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't you think you are missing the **annotations** used in the tutorial?? **@XmlRootElement** and **@XmlAttribute** before your class and methods, respectively??

Comment: @ShayHaned no, I edited the question to include my Message class. also I am not getting the error any more, however my application is terminated when I run it.

Comment: Obviously the edit helped in removing the exception atleast, but why would you want to call **super()** in the constructor of Message class? Becuase your class implements **Serializable**? Calling **super()** just because you are implementing **Serializable** makes no difference at all. And your application terminates, because you are **NOT PRINTING ANYTHING** on the console

Comment: @ShayHaned ok, I am expecting the xml file to be generated and that is not happening. can you advise why ?

Comment: @ShayHaned yeah I tried to change it to message.xml, but still not able to get the file

Comment: actually the file is created in the folder but it doesn't appear in the project!

thanks for the help

even the one with object.getClass().getName() + ".xml", got created.

Comment: Consider replacing the statement **JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.ExCourse.class);** to **JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());** . I couldn't even in my wildest dream understand what, **object.ExCourse.class** really meant

Comment: Just change **object.ExCourse.class** to **object.getClass()**. That should help finalize your problem :) . Sorry about the naming convention, but sometimes that does cause stupid unseen exceptions :)

Comment: @ShayHaned one thing is to use object.getClass().getSimpleName()

Comment: Yep I was about to point that out in the previous comments, but was hurrying for other things, indeed **object.getClass().getSimpleName()** would be the best practice :)